# How to check the correct typo of the first and last name in the list?

Tags: python

I am trying to check every word in my list if it contains right first letter of name and surname. I probably know how to check it if its in two separated lists. But i have this source of data:

```
data = ['Johnny Loom', 'frank Cedder', 'Marylin monroe', 'Joseph Monroe']
```

And the wanted result must be : Johnny Loom, Joseph Monroe

This is what i have now, but it doesnt work:

```
def capital(str_list):
    right = []
    wrong= []
    for n in str_list:
        if n[0].isupper():
            right .append(n)
        if not n[0].isupper():
            wrong.append(n)
    return right
```

Thanks for any advice how to solve it guys!

Comment: Why do you need the `wrong` list? You only add data, but don't use it for anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function to check if all the words present in the name start with an uppercase letter.

```
right = [
    name 
    for name in data
    if all(i[0].isupper() for i in name.split())
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt function called `istitle()` for this in python -

```
data = ['Johnny Loom', 'frank Cedder', 'Marylin monroe', 'Joseph Monroe']
output = []
for x in data:
    if x.istitle():
        output.append(x)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` to get the first and last name from the element and then use `and` to check for both:

```
def capital(str_list):
    right = []
    for n in str_list:
        first, last = n.split()
        if first[0].isupper() and last[0].isupper():
            right.append(n)
    return right

data = ['Johnny Loom', 'frank Cedder', 'Marylin monroe', 'Joseph Monroe']
print(capital(data))
```

Comment: Glad to be of help, @DanRais. Remember to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark which you found most helpful among all.

Answer (score 1):

This logic works for names with any number of words using `split()` and `isupper()`:

```
def isCapital(name):
    name_splited = name.split(' ')
    i = 0
    for names in name_splited:
        if names[0].isupper():
            i = i + 1
    if i == len(name_splited):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False) 

data_right  = [i for i in data if isCapital(i)]
data_right  
# ['Johnny Loom', 'Joseph Monroe']
```